# DBContext.SaveChanges() doesn't take effect on an existing database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, datagridview

I am using DataGridView and a binding navigator to list/edit some data (list of users). When I try to update a column on an existing row (user data), everything works (after clicking save button from a binding navigator).

**Current Setup**

Now, when I add new row, nothing happens. Database stays the same. I tried to handle some exceptions, but without luck, nothing is thrown:

```
  try
  {
      context.SaveChanges();
   }
     catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Debug.Write(ex);
  }
```

I also tried something like this:

```
try {
   context.SaveChanges();
}catch (DbUpdateException ex){
     Debug.Write(ex);
}
```

But I guess, that the first code would catch all thrown exceptions, so being explicit doesn't make difference.

How can I find a source of the problem ? Why I can't catch any exception?

**EDIT:**

I have two tables in a database, a User and a Privilege, thus I have created two data sources (seen from within Data Sources window). So, the `userBindingSource` has its DataSource set to `MyDb.user` and `privilegeBindingSource` has its DataSource set to `MyDb.privilege` datasource.

Comment: You are looking for an exception but apparently there isn't one. I would guess your context doesn't have any added entities, I think you need to look at how you have  your bindings setup.

Comment: @Crowcoder Okay, thanks. Can you be more specific. I have standard binding setup...I guess.

Comment: It is you as the OP who needs to be more specific :) [Add a minimal, complete and verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Crowcoder I knew you are going to say that :) I made an edit. I will try to add more info, but actually... I am not sure what is really important here.

Comment: [This example](https://github.com/crowcoder/EF6DataGridView) is in VB, but it demonstrates one way to bind a datagridview with EF and CRUD operations.

Comment: Actually, I have already seen this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682076(v=vs.113).aspx, so I am aware how it should be done @Crowcoder and what is even more odd, is, that this worked yesterday. Now, obviously, I have changed something, accidentally or not, but now it doesn't save data, so I was trying to find a way how to debug this, to find a reason why it isn't working. But, I would say that setup is the same as when it was working. Just strange. Also probably something silly.

Comment: Comment out your changes and then see if it works. If it does uncomment your changes in small steps and keep testing until something breaks it. Then you know what broke it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi But I can't say I have changed anything in that part of an app. I really can't see a difference. And yeah, I haven't enabled source control. That was the first silly thing I did. Also, most of the things are done in designer. So not that much code so far.